# Is it mandatory to set contamination value for isolation forest in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I'm going to build a model to identify anomalies in my dataset. I researched a lot and found out the isolation forest is the best one so for. In my dataset, I don't have any labels (that means the dataset only contains explanatory variables). But I have no idea to set the contamination parameter in the isolation forest(Most of the articles that explain already has output variable [labeled as anomaly], using that they calculate outlier-ratio and then set it as **contamination value**).

Is it mandatory to set it?. The default value for contamination is 0.1. Is it okay to ignore it? **if I didn't give value for it, **does it affect the model results?****

```
model = IsolationForest(contamination=0.1, n_estimators=1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not mandatory to set the contamination value. By default it is set to "auto".

> **contamination‘auto’ or float, default=’auto’** The amount of
> contamination of the data set, i.e. the proportion of outliers in the
> data set. Used when fitting to define the threshold on the scores of
> the samples.

[Reference in documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html)

You can therefore ignore it, but it can/will affect the model results, as the predict method makes use of the threshold, which is set by the contamination value.

> The predict method makes use of a threshold on the raw scoring
> function computed by the estimator. This scoring function is
> accessible through the `score_samples` method, while the threshold can
> be controlled by the `contamination` parameter.

[Reference in documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#novelty-and-outlier-detection)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643736/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?